# Puxar retorno de classe AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma classe `Main` que executa um método `receberSolicitantes()` com uma tarefa em *background*. Enquanto é executada, ela atualiza uma `progressBar`.

Tudo está funcionando perfeitamente com o método da seguinte forma:

```
public void receberSolicitantes() {
        JsonReceber receber = new JsonReceber(this, "solicitantes", this.progressBar);
        receber.execute();
    }
```

Mas quando eu coloco a linha `receber.get()` (como exibido mais abaixo) para buscar o retorno, o método `onProgressUpdate` (da classe assíncrona `JsonReceber`) só é executado no final do `doInBackground`, e assim, a `progressBar` não funciona.

Adicionado `receber.get()`:

```
public void receberSolicitantes() {
        JsonReceber receber = new JsonReceber(this, "solicitantes", this.pb);
        receber.execute();
        try {
            receber.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Como faço para buscar o retorno da execução em background ?**

Seria da mesma forma que faço com a `progressBar` levando na chamada

`JsonReceber receber = new JsonReceber(this, "solicitantes", this.progressBar)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se quer que o resultado da tarefa executada pela AsyncTask seja realizada assincronamente então não pode usar o método `get()`.

O método [get()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get()) obtém o resultado mas faz com que a execução do programa espere que ele seja calculado antes de continuar, não sendo por isso assíncrono.

Para que o resultado seja calculado assincronamente deve usar o método `execute()`.
O resultado pode ser obtido no método `onPostExecute()`, através do parâmetro nele declarado.

Veja na documentação como usar a [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).